# I can create-react-app but I cannot create-next-app

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, npx

I was wondering if anyone else has had issues using npx create-next-app [project name] command?

I am running these commands through Visual Studio Code Terminal

Create-react-app works just fine for me but whenever I try using npx create-next-app it gives me this error.

I am using Node version 16.10.0
[image]

Answer (score 1):

technically speaking if create-next-app is installed properly you should not be seeing this issue

if Before creating it manually. Try to install the create-next-app package

```
npm i create-next-app
```

Then you can do again:

```
npx create-next-app my-awesome-app
```